# How to switch between rendering and presenting framebuffers in iPhone OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, framebuffer

iPhone OpenGL ES 2.0..

- First frame, render to my framebuffer then present it (as it works by default in the template OpenGL ES application).
- On the next frame, I want to use that rendered framebuffer as an input in to my shaders, while rendering to another framebuffer and presenting that 2nd framebuffer.
- The next frame, I want to use framebuffer2 as input in to my shaders, while rendering to the first framebuffer again.
- Repeat

How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to set up a renderbuffer that has a texture backing it using code like the following:

```
// Offscreen position framebuffer object
glGenFramebuffers(1, &positionFramebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, positionFramebuffer);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &positionRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, positionRenderbuffer);

glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8_OES, FBO_WIDTH, FBO_HEIGHT);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, positionRenderbuffer); 

// Offscreen position framebuffer texture target
glGenTextures(1, &positionRenderTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, positionRenderTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, FBO_WIDTH, FBO_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, positionRenderTexture, 0);
```

Switching buffers is as simple as using code like this:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, positionFramebuffer);        
glViewport(0, 0, FBO_WIDTH, FBO_HEIGHT);
```

You can then render to that buffer and display the resulting texture by passing it into a simple shader that displays it within a rectangular piece of geometry.  That texture can also be fed into a shader which renders into another similar renderbuffer that is backed by a texture, and so on.

If you need to do some CPU-based processing or readout, you can use `glReadPixels()` to pull in the pixels from this offscreen renderbuffer.

For examples of this, you can try out my sample applications [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ColorTracking.zip) and [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ShaderExamples.zip).  The former does processing of video frames from a camera, with one of the settings allowing for a passthrough of the video while doing processing in an offscreen renderbuffer.  The latter example renders into a cube map texture at one point, then uses that texture to do environment mapping on a teapot.

Comment: That's a fantastic answer.  Why do you call it "position" Framebuffer?

Comment: @Nektarios - That was code lifted from the first example project I linked.  For a color tracking algorithm, I replaced every pixel that's within a certain threshold with the relative X position in the red component and relative Y position within the green component (with the others being 1.0).  Therefore, after a pass on the image, the average color of all pixels passing the test is the centroid of the object being tracked.  See here for more: http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/10/22/gpu-accelerated-video-processing-mac-and-ios